# Ruby bug appears only when using print statements inside a block for array.each

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

If I call the function `anagrams` below in *irb*, I get a non-empty hash container as expected. But if you comment out the `print "No Key\n"` line, the returned hash container is now empty. In fact for all elements in list the code in the `elsif` branch seems to execute. Either I'm going nuts or there is a nasty bug here:

```
def anagrams(list = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', 'scream'])
        aHash = Hash.new()
        list.each { |el|
            aKey = el.downcase.chars.sort.to_a.hash
            if aHash.key?(aKey)
                # print "Has Key\n"
                aHash[aKey] << el
            elsif
                # print "No Key\n"
                aHash[aKey] = [el]
            end
        }

        return aHash
end
```

I have the following versions of *ruby* and *irb* installed:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)
```

Comment: Just a note: it's convention in Ruby to use `do`/`end` instead of `{`/`}` when the block spans multiple lines.

Comment: Also, I can't replicate this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using an `elsif` where you mean `else`. This:

```
elsif
    print "No Key\n"
    aHash[aKey] = [el]
```

is misleading formatting, it is actually interpreted more like this:

```
elsif(print "No Key\n")
    aHash[aKey] = [el]
```

but `print` returns `nil` so the logic is like this:

```
elsif(nil)
    aHash[aKey] = [el]
```

and `nil` is false in a boolean context so `aHash[aKey] = [el]` never occurs. If you remove the `print` then you end up with this:

```
elsif(aHash[aKey] = [el])
```

and the assignment occurs; the assignment is also true in a boolean context (because an Array is) but the truthiness is irrelevant in this case.

You want to use `else` here:

```
if aHash.key?(aKey)
    aHash[aKey] << el
else
    aHash[aKey] = [el]
end
```

Even better would be to use a Hash with an Array (via a block) as its default value:

```
aHash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
```

and then you don't need the `if` at all, you can just do this:

```
list.each do |el|
    aKey = el.downcase.chars.sort.to_a.hash
    aHash[aKey] << el
end
```

And you can use anything as a key in a Ruby Hash so you don't even need to `.to_a.hash`, you can simply use the Array itself as the key; furthermore, `sort` will give you an array so you don't even need the `to_a`:

```
list.each { |el| aHash[el.downcase.chars.sort] << el }
```

Someone will probably complain about the `return` at the end of your method so I'll do it: you don't need the `return` at the end of your method, just say `aHash` and it will be the method's return value:

```
def anagrams(list = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', 'scream'])
    aHash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
    list.each { |el| aHash[el.downcase.chars.sort] << el }
    aHash
end
```

You could also use [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to compress it even more:

```
def anagrams(list = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', 'scream'])
    list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }) do |el, h|
        h[el.downcase.chars.sort] << el
    end
end
```

but I'd probably do it like this to cut down on the noise:

```
def anagrams(list = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', 'scream'])
    h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
    list.each_with_object(h) { |el, h| h[el.downcase.chars.sort] << el }
end
```